# Can I move to another country and keep my Belgian bank account?

Tags: banking, belgium

I'm an EU citizen and I have been living and working in Belgium for the last few years. I'm planning to move back to my home country (also in Eu) in a few months, and I'd like to keep my Belgian bank account. Is this generally possible with all Belgian banks? Or can I only keep the account if my address is in Belgium? It seems that ING offers such service: https://www.ing.be/en/retail/daily-banking/expats/after-your-departure, but I haven't found any info about other banks

Comment: No idea about Belgium,but it's perfectly OK in the Netherlands. The only important limitation is that you can't have any lines of credit (e.g. overdraft facility) on an account with a foreign address.

Comment: I think – but am not entirely sure – that it's illegal for an EU bank to only serve residents or citizens of a particular country or region. So you should be able to keep the account. However, you may have to do tax stuff yourself.